# How can I configure OptaPlanner's partitioned search that local search options can be applied individually to each of created partitions?

Tags: optaplanner

I use the partitioned search feature for a very large VRPTW class problem. I have implemented a SolutionPartitioner that does its job very well.

Unfortunately sometimes there are partitions of 1000 customers, and in this case I use nearby selection in order to speedup calculations. Unfortunately for other smaller partitions (under 200 customers) the same nearby selection configuration gives worse results than without nearby selection.

Moreover using some heuristics I can specify a set of custom "smart" moves (in move factories) that help in finding optimal solution faster, but sometimes it is inappropriate to use all these moves to each of created partition.

Is it possible to configure local search options to each partition individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently in 7.7, it's not possible to configure different child solver algorithms for different partitions, because `PartitionedSearchPhaseConfig.java` doesn't support that (yet?).

Please create a strawman of how the solver config XML would look like, in a text file. And then [create a jira](https://issues.jboss.org/projects/PLANNER/) for it.

This relates to (unimplemented) support for **hyper-heuristics**, which is the ability to configure the solver config to tweak the algorithm based on the input size, by for example using different selectors.

I think that hyper-heuristics might outright solve this, and that fact that it's partitioned doesn't matter, because the `<hyperheuristic>` would be nested into the `<partionedSearch>` and would switch to nearby and non-nearby per partition as required.

Comment: I think that the solver (its base class) should support dynamic phase configuration reload - like a hot swap. In my app I can terminate a solver, save its working solution (VRP chains layout), and then reload solver using a different configuration. It is like a pause-resume feature along with a configuration change ability. I think it would be ideally to have an access to each partition solver, where you could listen for these best score change events, and utilize a new feature that would allow you to reload local search phase configuration, and continue calculations.

Comment: or as the academics call it: "hyper-heuristics" :)